# Not able to extend Mage_Cms_IndexController in my custom module, Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to extend `Mage_Cms_IndexController` controller but nothing is happening. My code is under `app/code/local/Ash/Test`  .

code of `app/code/local/Ash/Test/etc/config.xml`

```
 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <ash_test>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ash_Test</module>
                <frontName>ash_test</frontName>                 
            </args>
        </ash_test>
        <cms>
            <args>                    
                <modules>
                    <Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">
                        Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms
                    </Ash_Test>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </cms>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And controller location in my module is

```
app/code/local/Ash/Test/controllers/Frontend/Cms/IndexController
```

and code is

```
 require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Cms').DS.'IndexController.php';
class Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms_IndexController extends Mage_Cms_IndexController
{

public function indexAction($coreRoute = null)
    {
        echo __FILE__;

    }
}
```

I`m not getting what is wrong in it. Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove white space around following code,

```
<Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">
    Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms
</Ash_Test>
```

It should be as follows,

```
<Ash_Test before="Mage_Cms">Ash_Test_Frontend_Cms</Ash_Test>
```

Flush cache and then check. It should work.

> You cannot have any whitespace around your controller name in
>   config.xml. Magento will silently fail to pick up your override and
>   just use the controller from the core.